# Joomla search by year

Tags: joomla, search-box

I want to make a Joomla website which stores some article about history, but I don't have any idea on how to make a search box which can search the year. I want to categories the article by year and make an menu which categories the year too.

Comment: Use smart search as it will pick up the years in the texts and titles as words. Then you can link to a filtered search.

Comment: This old question is far too broad, and can be put on hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use years as tags. To do so, when entering an article, type in year in a tag field, and click save.

Then in default Joomla search you will be able to get search results by tag.